# how to subtract quantity in my POS table to quantity in product table

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

example. i have product table which have a quantity etc.

```
item name: Shoes.
Quantity: 20
```

POS table. If the user bought the bag which have a quantity 20.

```
Itenm name: Shoes
Quantity: 5
```

the question is. how can i subtract the quantity : 5 in POS table to the quantity 20 in product table. thanks.

Comment: Please show any code that you've tried already.

Answer (score 0):

You could join the two tables on item name and do the subtraction.

```
select p.item_name,
    p.quantity - po.quantity
from product p
join POS po on p.item_name = po.item_name;
```

If you need to update the product table with the difference, then:

```
update product p
join POS po on p.item_name = po.item_name
set p.quantity = p.quantity - po.quantity;
```

If there are multiple rows with same item name, you probably want to aggregation them first and then join to update:

```
update product p
join (
    select item_name,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    from POS
    group by item_name
    ) po on p.item_name = po.item_name
set p.quantity = p.quantity - po.quantity;
```

Comment: where do i put that code? in a button or? sorry just a beginner.

Comment: @Jay - um.. [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) will get you started.